# Alternating Textview and Imageview inside a Scrollview

Tags: android, android-scrollview

I'm trying to have an alternating text and image in my scrollview. There are no errors on the code, however when I try to run the application. Its force closing. I'm new to android studio. How can I fix this? I tried to search answers here but I cant seem to find the solution that I'm looking for.

Here is my code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity ="center"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/scrollView">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            android:text="hello"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cheese_1"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="hi" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cheese_2"/>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: post your java class and your logcat too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it work

```
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:gravity="center"
                  android:orientation="vertical">

        <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:gravity ="center"
                    android:fillViewport="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                    android:id="@+id/scrollView">

            <LinearLayout
                  android:layout_width="match_parent"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical">
             <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="hello"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cheese_1"/>


            <TextView
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="#000"
                android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="18sp"
                android:text="hi"/>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="15dp"
                android:layout_height="15dp"
                android:src="@drawable/cheese_2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, This helps me a lot. And now I understand

Answer (score 2):

instead use a `Listview` or `Recyclerview` and have a custom `Adapter` to show image and text alternatively. That would be lot better and controllable.

if you still want to use only scrollview you can have only one direct child to scrollview.Add a linear layout as a child of scrollview and all image and textviews as children to that linearlayout as follows

```
<ScrollView ..>
  <LinearLayout ..>
    <TextView ../>
    <ImageView ../>
    <TextView ../>
 </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

Scrollview can contains only one child in it. so put you imageViews and TextViews in LinearLayout and then put LinearLayout in ScrollView.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 0):

You have include too many direct children in the scroll view. Scroll view can handle only one child at time so m you have to wrap your all other views under only one view.

so your xml will look like this now

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity ="center"
                android:fillViewport="true"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
                android:id="@+id/scrollView">
    <LinearLayout
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            android:text="hello"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cheese_1"/>


        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:textColorLink="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            android:text="hi" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="15dp"
            android:layout_height="15dp"
            android:src="@drawable/cheese_2"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

This should work now.

Comment: Thank you for your response.